# Action camera stops recording on 18 minutes

Tags: camera, video, video-recording

I am using Denver ACK-8062W action camera to record while I'm driving my motorcycle and it always stops on 18 minutes, I tried using "loop video" feature where the camera starts a new clip after 5 minutes, but the camera records 3 5 minute video clips and stops on the 4th clip's 3rd minute.

It doesn't appear to be a file size limitation, because the 5 minute clips are bigger in size then the 3 minute.

It doesn't appear to be a storage limitation, as I had 20 GB of free storage before the recording began.

It doesn't appear to be a battery limitation, as I had full battery after the recording had finished.

the format file is FAT32 and the camera doesn't overheat. Can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure if this is an Android problem. Are you using the camera with an app? Have you been able to run the action camera for long periods not connected to any app without issue? At a guess, might be a overheating problem.

Comment: Possible overheating problem of the camera or the micro SD card which is getting too slow when heated up to write the data in real-time. Redo the test in a cool environment and see if the max duration changes.